# Customizing SharePoint Server 2010 Survey "Fill-in" Question

Tags: survey-list

I am working with a SharePoint Server 2010 survey that contains some questions about allow fill-in responses.  Is there a simple way to change the wording of these fill-in questions?  Instead of "Specify your own value," I would like them to say something along the lines as "Other" (per project sponsor request).

I found this in regards to the [WSS 3.0 and MOSS 2007](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcustomization/thread/d296a98e-c2b4-4c61-8bf4-627ba0754fb7) customization:

However, it seems to me that there should be an easier way to change the wording of this question without having to edit the default master page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those cases were I like to use jQuery to modify the rendered html without any impact to the MasterPage or centralized templates.  It should only take a simple selector to identify the container, and swap out the "Other" content with the desired label.

Comment: Is jQuery supported natively by SharePoint 2010 or do I have to integrate it?

Comment: I'm not sure which specific script libraries and versions are available off hand.  I typically manage my own library reference.  If it isn't deployed to the farm you can always reference once of the online versions such as Google API.